# I uninstalled a package using pip uninstall but I am unable to re install it

Tags: pip, installation, package

This is what I typed after using pip uninstall matplotlib:

```
pip install matplotlib
```

But this is the output:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement matplotlib (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for matplotlib
```

I am running this on a Mac and I am new to Python. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: can u do a pip --version?

Comment: When i type pip --version, I get 9.0.1

Comment: also python --version , as i just tested your above with pip version 9.0.3 and python version 3.6.4 on windows and it worked

Answer (score 1):

This probably because of your TLS version. starting yesterday you can't use a TLS version below 1.2, you might need to upgrade your python version.

From python status page:

> The rolling brownouts have been upgraded to a blackout, TLSv1.0 and >TLSv1.1 will be rejected with a HTTP 403 at all times.
>
> Posted about 17 hours ago. Apr 08, 2018 - 15:49 UTC

you can check your TLS version by running this code:

```
import json
import urllib2
print json.load(urllib2.urlopen('https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check'))['tls_version']
```